# How to implement ops::Mul on a struct so it works with numerical types as well as another struct?

Tags: rust, traits

I have implemented a `Point3D` struct:

```
use std::ops;
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct Point3D {
    pub x: f32,
    pub y: f32,
    pub z: f32,
}

impl ops::Add<&Point3D> for &Point3D {
    type Output = Point3D;
    fn add(self, rhs: &Point3D) -> Point3D {
        Point3D {
            x: self.x + rhs.x,
            y: self.y + rhs.y,
            z: self.z + rhs.z,
        }
    }
}

impl ops::Sub<&Point3D> for &Point3D {
    type Output = Point3D;
    fn sub(self, rhs: &Point3D) -> Point3D {
        Point3D {
            x: self.x - rhs.x,
            y: self.y - rhs.y,
            z: self.z - rhs.z,
        }
    }
}

impl ops::Mul<&Point3D> for &Point3D {
    type Output = f32;
    fn mul(self, rhs: &Point3D) -> f32 {
        self.x * rhs.x + self.y * rhs.y + self.z * rhs.z
    }
}

//Scalar impl of ops::Mul here

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    #[test]
    fn addition_point_3D() {
        let point1 = Point3D {
            x: 1.0,
            y: 2.0,
            z: 3.0,
        };
        let point2 = Point3D {
            x: 4.0,
            y: 5.0,
            z: 6.0,
        };
        let result = &point1 + &point2;
        assert_eq!(
            result,
            Point3D {
                x: 5.0,
                y: 7.0,
                z: 9.0
            },
            "Testing Addition with {:?} and {:?}",
            point1,
            point2
        );
    }

    #[test]
    fn subtraction_point_3D() {
        let point1 = Point3D {
            x: 1.0,
            y: 2.0,
            z: 3.0,
        };
        let point2 = Point3D {
            x: 4.0,
            y: 5.0,
            z: 6.0,
        };
        let result = &point1 - &point2;
        assert_eq!(
            result,
            Point3D {
                x: -3.0,
                y: -3.0,
                z: -3.0
            },
            "Testing Subtraction with {:?} and {:?}",
            point1,
            point2
        );
    }

    #[test]
    fn point3D_point3D_multiplication() {
        let point1 = Point3D {
            x: 1.0,
            y: 2.0,
            z: 3.0,
        };
        let point2 = Point3D {
            x: 4.0,
            y: 5.0,
            z: 6.0,
        };
        let result = &point1 * &point2;
        assert_eq!(
            result, 32.0,
            "Testing Multiplication with {:?} and {:?}",
            point1, point2
        );
    }

    /*
    #[test]
    fn point3D_scalar_multiplication() {
        let point1 = Point3D { x: 1.0, y: 2.0, z: 3.0};
        let scalar = 3.5;
        let result = &point1 * &scalar;
        assert_eq!(result, Point3D { x: 3.5, y: 7.0, z: 10.5 }, "Testing Multiplication with {:?} and {:?}", point1, scalar);
    }
    */
}
```

I would like to use generics in my multiplication trait so that if I pass it another `Point3D` class it will implement the dot product, but if I pass it a basic numeric type (integer, f32, unsigned integer, f64) it will multiply `x`, `y`, and `z` by the scalar value.  How would would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this with generics you first need to make your `Point3D` struct accept generics, like

```
use std::ops::{Mul, Add};

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct Point3D<T> {
    pub x: T,
    pub y: T,
    pub z: T,
}
```

And your implementation of multiplication of `Point3D` with a numeric type would be

```rust
impl<T> Mul<T> for &Point3D<T>
    where T: Mul<Output=T> + Copy
{
    type Output = Point3D<T>;
    fn mul(self, rhs: T) -> Self::Output {
        Point3D {
            x: self.x * rhs,
            y: self.y * rhs,
            z: self.z * rhs,
        }
    }
}
```

We have the `where` clause because our generic `T` would need to implement the traits `Mul` and `Copy` as well. `Copy` because we need to copy `rhs` to use in all the three multiplications.

Your dot product implementation would also need to change according to

```rust
impl<T> Mul<&Point3D<T>> for &Point3D<T> 
    where T: Mul<Output=T> + Add<Output=T> + Copy
{
    type Output = T;
    fn mul(self, rhs: &Point3D<T>) -> Self::Output {
        self.x * rhs.x + self.y * rhs.y + self.z * rhs.z
    }
}
```

with the `Add` because we of course need to be able to add the generics `T` here.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean something like that?

```
impl ops::Mul<f32> for &Point3D {
    type Output = Point3D;
    fn mul(self, rhs: f32) -> Point3D {
        Point3D {
            x: self.x * rhs,
            y: self.y * rhs,
            z: self.z * rhs
        }
    }
}
```

This would allow you to do the following:

```
let point = Point3D { x: 1.0, y: 2.0, z: 3.0};
let result = &point * 4.0;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.  But no. I do not want to implement a Multiplcation operator for each type, for example (uints, ints, or f64). I would like, ideally one implementation that work work with both my Point3D struct or I would be ok with two.  One for the specific case of the Point3D * Point3D and then a second case for all other numeric types.  This is what my question was about.  How to write the Multiplication Trait in a generic fashion.